# How to Set state to another class in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a bottom navigation bar witch display a class according to the current index,
I used a ternary condition to check witch class to display on the first index using this code :

```
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      static String homeindex = "main";
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    final greencol = HexColor("#2f7e7b");
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      static int _currentindex = 0;
    
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        final tabs = [
          (Home.homeindex == 'main') ? Homehome() : Green(),
          Assistant(),
          Profile(),
        ];
 bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: 55,
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: _currentindex,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              selectedItemColor: greencol,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              selectedLabelStyle:
                  GoogleFonts.roboto(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              iconSize: 25,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home_outlined,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Home',
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.mic_outlined,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Assistance',
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person_outlined,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Profile',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentindex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

using a static string called home index I'm trying to change the display widget on the first index using set state from another class :

```
class Homehome extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homehome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomehomeState createState() => _HomehomeState();
}

class _HomehomeState extends State<Homehome> {

.....


child: ButtonTheme(
                                minWidth: 20.0,
                                height: 30.0,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      Home.homeindex = 'greenhouse';
                                      print(Home.homeindex);
                                    });
                                  },
```

but it's only setting state to the current class widget.

what's the easiest way to rebuild the widget from the last page ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring your void callback from Homehome one level up to Home, then call setState to update the Home widget.

```
class Homehome extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homehome({Key? key, required this.onPressedMyButton }) : super(key: key);

   final VoidCallBack onPressedMyButton;


.....


child: ButtonTheme(
                                minWidth: 20.0,
                                height: 30.0,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: widget.onPressedMyButton,
```

In your Home widget:

```
.....

final tabs = [
          (Home.homeindex == 'main') ? Homehome(onPressedMyButton: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          Home.homeindex = 'greenhouse';
                                          print(Home.homeindex);
                                        });
                                      }, ) : Green(),
          Assistant(),
          Profile(),
        ];

.....
```